# How to prevent duplicate record in DataGridView in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have Data GridView named grdInformationDetails that loads on the load Event of SearchInformation Form. On a Double click Event of this GridView, I have a Code that sent that rows values to AddForm Form for update record. After Update, the GridView Duplicate the records. I already set the datasource of the GridView to null before loading Record from database and also autoGeneratedColumn property set to false. I don't understand where i am doing wrong. Please Help.

Here is the Double Click Event

```
 private void grdInformationDetails_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int rowToUpdate = grdInformationDetails.Rows.GetFirstRow(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
        int employeeId = Convert.ToInt32(grdInformationDetails.Rows[rowToUpdate].Cells["id"].Value);
        ShowAddInfoForm(employeeId, true);
    }
```

Here is ShowAddInfoForm Code

```
 private void ShowAddInfoForm(int employeeId, bool isupdate)
    {
        AddInfo ainfo = new AddInfo();
        ainfo.EmployeeId = employeeId;
        ainfo.Isupdate = isupdate;
        ainfo.ShowDialog();
        grdInformationDetails.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        grdInformationDetails.DataSource = null;
        LoadGridView();
    }
```

Here is the image of the record that is present in the database
[image]

Here is the duplicate Record after Update
[image]

UPDATE: Here is the LoadGridView method for Loading GridView

```
 private void LoadGridView()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM TableInfo", con);
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                ad.Fill(dtEmployees);
                grdInformationDetails.DataSource = dtEmployees;
                grdInformationDetails.Columns["Id"].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Most probably the answer lies in the code not shown here - `LoadGridView`

Comment: I add the Method that load Data to Grid View

Comment: So it's not a DataGridView issue, but data set/table issue. Since you are reusing `dtEmployees` field, `ad.Fill(dtEmployees);` duplicates the records in case you haven't defined primary key on the DataTable - see [DataAdapter.Fill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill?view=netframework-4.7.2). You can verify that in the code by checking  `dtEmployees` right after the `Fill` method.

Comment: I have set a global DataTable i-e dtEmployees because i want to filter data in GridView for Searching Purpose. Should i place DataTable inside the LoadGrid view Method?

Comment: Thanks for Highlighting the Issue. I just put a single line code before filling the adapter i-e
 dtEmployees.Clear();
 ad.Fill(dtEmployees);
and it solves the problem. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

You could change your sql as follows:

```
SELECT distinct column_a, column_b FROM TableInfo
```

or you could convert the data once you get it back to linq, and use the DISTINCT method e.g.

```
ad.Distinct()
```

A third option is to loop through your grid and delete any duplicate values.